# The difference between LayoutInflater.inflate and findViewById

Tags: android, android-widget, layout-inflater, findviewbyid

What is the difference between getting a reference to a widget like this:

```
TableRow row = findViewById(R.id.table_row);
```

and:

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
```

Is there also a difference when the `TableRow` is a root of its layout or if its just a small part of a layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference...

The first one is retrieving an existing widget within your activity.

The second one is reading in an XML file and is creating *new* widgets. The second one is also somewhat buggy, in that you infrequently want to use `LayoutInflater.from()` (you typically use `getLayoutInflater()` on your `Activity`), and you infrequently want to use that `inflate()` variant (if you do not provide a parent container, layout resources with a root `RelativeLayout` element will misbehave).

> Is there also a difference when the TableRow is a root of its layout or if its just a small part of a layout?

Yes. The difference is the same as before: retrieving an existing widget or creating a new one.

Answer (score 4):

**1)** Using

```
TableRow row = findViewById(R.id.table_row);
```

you are **simply obtaining a reference** to a `View` with id *R.id.table_row* which has already been created and inflated in the current layout (where *current* means the `Activtiy`'s layout or the `View` that you are defining).

**2)** Using

```
TableRow row = (TableRow)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.table_row, null);
```

You are **inflating** (which means creating) a new views hierarchy based on the XML definition contained in *R.layout.table_row*. Since you are not passing the parent View parameter in the *inflate()* method, you will need to add the resulting hierarchy manually to an existent container.